# Binance Extract Futures Prices

Tags: python, api, binance

I would like to extract the price of the future "ETHUSD Quarterly 0625" from Binance using the Python API.

For example if it was ETHUSDT I would use:

```
from binance.client import Client as BClient
client = BClient(api_key="****", api_secret="****")
symbol = "ETHUSDT"
client.get_klines(symbol=symbol, interval="5m")
```

but this does not work:

```
from binance.client import Client as BClient
client = BClient(api_key="****", api_secret="****")
symbol = "ETHUSDT Quarterly 0625"
client.get_klines(symbol=symbol, interval="5m")
```

Any help please?

Comment: What specifically is your question? Where are you stuck and what errors do you have?

Comment: There are no errors in this code.

Comment: thank you guys, I amended the question, it's about finding a way to extract the prices of a different financial instrument Futures.